# Parse Python code given as string and find if a variable is used

Tags: python

I have a string with Python code

```py
code = '''
I = 1

II = 2

print(II)
'''
```

and need to know if a variable from the string with code was used.

I tried using regex:

```py
import re

def was_used(varname, codestr):
    used = re.findall(varname, codestr)
    
    return len(used) >= 2

print(was_used('I', code))
```

but it doesn't work because of messy variable names.

output:

```
True
```

Comment: It doesn't work for other reasons too. If the code is `I = 1; I = 2` it's still not used.

Comment: If you are really just asking how to not get `II` when searching for `I`, research word delimiters in regular expressions. But if you want to do this properly, you need to parse the Python code. The standard library has a module for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing of Python source code should be done with an Abstract Syntax Tree parser. Feel free to use the standard library [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module:

```
import ast
from typing import Set, Tuple

# The input code
code = '''
I = 1

II = 2

print(II)
'''

# A visitor that tracks the use of variables
class VariableVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def __init__(self, variables: Tuple[str]) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.variables = variables
        self.found = set()

    def visit(self, node: ast.AST) -> Set[str]:
        # Use the standard visit, and then return the set of found variables
        super().visit(node)
        return self.found

    def visit_Name(self, node: ast.Name):
        # For all Name nodes, check if the id is in the list of variables.
        if node.id in self.variables:
            self.found.add(node.id)

# Convert the input code to an AST
tree = ast.parse(code)
# A tuple of variables to track
variables = ("I")
visitor = VariableVisitor()
# See which variables were found in the sourcecode
found = visitor.visit(tree)

print(found)
```

This outputs:

```py
{'I'}
```

This program will first parse the code into an Abstract Syntax Tree, and then use a custom NodeVisitor class to "visit" all nodes in this AST. We can specify special behaviour whenever it visits a Name node, i.e. the node that is used whenever a variable is used, defined, etc. We can then check whether the name of that Name node corresponds with any of the variables that we are interested in (which we pass as a Tuple to `VariableVisitor`), and then the `visit` method will return a set with these 'found' variables.

Note that this has a weakness, i.e. that `print` and other functions or classes are also stored as a Name node, so if you also supplied `"print"` as a variable, then this program would say that "print" was used as a variable.

See [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) for the documentation on AST, and [`NodeVisitor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) as well as [`parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) for the more specific details.

Feel free to `print(ast.dump(tree, indent=2))` on some sample programs to get a feel of the AST structure.